# Laravel вывести только нужные поля из таблицы

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, controller

Такое обращение выводит все поля из объединенных таблиц

```
$model = Model::with('table1', 'table2')
                ->whereHas('table1',function($t)use($fackt){ 
                    $t->where('name','LIKE','%'.$fackt.'%');
                })
                ->get()
```

На больших таблицах вывод всех полей не самое скоростное решение, как вывести только нужные мне поля? Пробовал использовать такой вид запроса, но он отрабатывает не правильно

```
 $model = Model::select('col1', 'col2')->with('table1', 'table2')
                ->whereHas('table1',function($t)use($fackt){ 
                    $t->where('name','LIKE','%'.$fackt.'%');
                })
                ->get()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$model = Model::select(['col1', 'col2'])->with('table1', 'table2')
                ->whereHas('table1',function($t)use($fackt){ 
                    $t->select(['id', 'column1', 'column2'])->where('name','LIKE','%'.$fackt.'%');
                })
                ->get()
```

Только нужно выбирать еще те поля, вроде бы, по которым `laravel` связывает ваши модели